Run python scripts with cron schedules using Powershell
Am new to powershell, So I want to know if we can run python scripts having cron schedules in powershell. I dont want to use windows task scheduler.
also my python.exe and the .py scripts are placed in different locations, not sure if that information is crucial.
P.S. I am planning to schedule few python scripts in client servers, so not necessary that everyone would use Windows OS.

Why use powershell if you are going to deploy cross-platform? search for cross platform cron cli

How would you use PowerShell? Are you planning to have cron run a PowerShell script that runs a Python script?

I need to specify the cron schedules in the powershell to run the python scripts
